# how to insert a object in mongodb using spring

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot, object

[required format image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1z771.png)

I want to object data into MongoDB using spring and I have hardcoded it.
please how to write a schema for that and I have taken it as an example only.
I have a different type of categories in it I have taken only clothes.
please tell me how to write one schema for a different type of categories and query too.

please find the attachment for your reference

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend going though [Spring Data MongoDB](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/3.0.4.RELEASE/reference/html/#mapping-usage) documentation for specifics on mapping java objects to MongoDB documents. Your case would look similar to:

```
@Document
public class Clothes {

  @Id
  private ObjectId id;

  private Men men;
  private Women women;

  // getters & setters
}
```

You would need to define each sub class but this should be the gist of it.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is create a simple POJO (Plain Old Java Object) and with that you can insert that object into the data base. The the following example:

```
@Document
public class OAuthModel implements Serializable {

    @Id
    String username;

    @Indexed
    String oAuthID;

    @Indexed
    String type;
    
// Getter and Setters and Construct.
}
```

When I insert this object in the DB by calling:

```
OAuthModel authModel = new OAuthModel(username,firebaseToken.getUid(), OAuthHosts.GOOGLE.getType());
oAuthRepo.insert(authModel);
```

It will then be seen as this in the Database:
[image]

Keep in mind this will work no matter what your object looks like, you can have hashmaps etc. The should be a built in serialization.

Comment: i am in the entry-level so could u please explain me and I required same like in the image format

Comment: Sure. So when we send data, in this case objects. We want to have want to convert that to a standerized form. In most cases that is a format called JSON. With the data in JSON format we can convert data to a JSON and vice versa. This is know as serialization. So with the `@Document` annotation we tell spring to generate the JSON automatically when we save data in our mongo database. No matter what type of data you have, arrays, double, ints, etc.

Comment: in other word have an object with all the data you need, that is the fields. add the `@Document` annotation above the class and then with your repo class do `repo.insert(TheObjectYouWant)`

Comment: tried with @Document saving empty data in the document. if possible pls tell me the schema

Comment: Im sorry Im a little lost. You need help with creating the data schema?